# Why FloatingActionButton is not shown

Tags: flutter

I try to show floating button on list view long press, but floating button is not shown.
Any ideas why?

I use the following code:

```
return GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            print('test');
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                print('test1');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            );
```

---

UPDATE 1

I have updated post with larger code view for build process better understanding...
I am adding "Dodaj" button that works fine so far and would like to add another one, "Usuń" shown after list view item long press.
Could you please take a look at this code and advise what I am doing wrong?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          //addItem();
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        label: const Text('Dodaj'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Lista zakupowa'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  // function to display fetched data on screen
  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        int customCompare(PostListDetails a, PostListDetails b) {
          if (a.status != b.status) {
            return a.status!.toInt() - b.status!.toInt();
          }
          final int categoryCompare = a.kategoria.toString().compareTo(b.kategoria.toString());
          if (categoryCompare != 0) {
            return categoryCompare;
          }
          return a.nazwa.toString().compareTo(b.nazwa.toString());
        }
        return GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            print('test1');
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                print('test2');
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            color: post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
            height: 50,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                    child: Column(
                    ...
                    ),
                  ),
                   Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                    ...
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
            ),
            ),
            );
          },
        );
    }
```

---

UPDATE 2

I have modified the code accordingly, but no luck this time... onlongpress button does not show up after long press on listview item.
This code should create a listview with a list of items and one floating button "+ Dodaj" that should be always visible (this part works fine).
I would like also to create after a long press on an item a "Usuń" button... this part does not work, I mean button is not visible.("test1" and "test2" are not printed).

The code now looks as follows:

```
bool showButton = false;

@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          //addList();
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        label: const Text('Dodaj'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text('Lista zakupowa'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: signUserOut,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text("Brak danych...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  // function to display fetched data on screen
  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        int customCompare(PostListDetails a, PostListDetails b) {
          if (a.status != b.status) {
            return a.status!.toInt() - b.status!.toInt();
          }
          final int categoryCompare = a.kategoria.toString().compareTo(b.kategoria.toString());
          if (categoryCompare != 0) {
            return categoryCompare;
          }
          return a.nazwa.toString().compareTo(b.nazwa.toString());
        }
        GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            print('test1');
            setState(() => showButton = true);
          },
        );
        showButton ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            print('test2');
            //removeList();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text('Usuń'),
        ) : null;
        return Container(
          color: post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
          height: 50,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(post.nazwa!, textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15,color: Colors.black)),
                      Text('${post.waga!.toString()} g.', textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 15,color: Colors.grey))
                    ]
                    ),
                  ),
                   Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Row(
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 10,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                CatIcon(imagePath: (Cat2Ico(post.kategoria!.toString()))),
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {post.status = Bool2Int(value!);});
                                    saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!, index);
                                    posts.sort(customCompare);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ]
                            ),
                          )
                      ]
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
            ),
          );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are not using the `FloatingActionButton` anywhere, you are just creating an instance, I can't provide you an answer since there isn't enough code but try to render it conditionally by updating a Boolean variable whenever the button is clicked

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with more details. Could you please take a look at UPDATE 2 section and advise what I am doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, In your code, you have two FloatingActionButton (FAB) widgets: one that should always be visible and another that should only be visible after a long press on a ListView item, to Achieve this:

1. You utilize a boolean variable named `showButton` initialized to false. This variable determines whether the additional FAB should be shown or not. In your code, you conditionally render the FAB using `if` statement (we will be using column, ternary operator won't work):

```
if(showButton)
FloatingActionButton.extended(...)
```

2. In the context of the Scaffold's `floatingActionButton` property, you wrap both FABs in a Column to arrange them vertically:

```
Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: Column(
      children: [
         FloatingActionButton.extended(...), // // The FAB that should always be visible
         if(showButton)
         FloatingActionButton.extended(...)// The FAB that will be visible after a long press
]),);
```

3. Inside the long press event handler, you use `setState` to update the screen and set the value of `showButton` to true:

```
GestureDetector(
   onLongPress: () {
      setState(() => showButton = true);
},),
```

in summary this is how it applies on the code you've provided:

```
bool showButton = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: Column(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            // addList();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text('Dodaj'),
        ),
        if (showButton)
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              print('test2');
              // removeList();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            label: const Text('Usuń'),
          ),
      ],
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      title: const Text('Lista zakupowa'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: signUserOut,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
        future: postsFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return buildPosts(snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Text("Brak danych...");
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: posts.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final post = posts[index];

      int customCompare(PostListDetails a, PostListDetails b) {
        if (a.status != b.status) {
          return a.status!.toInt() - b.status!.toInt();
        }
        final int categoryCompare = a.kategoria.toString().compareTo(b.kategoria.toString());
        if (categoryCompare != 0) {
          return categoryCompare;
        }
        return a.nazwa.toString().compareTo(b.nazwa.toString());
      }

      return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          print('test1');
          setState(() => showButton = true);
        },
        child: Container(
          color: post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.5, horizontal: 0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
          height: 50,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      post.nazwa!,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${post.waga!.toString()} g.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(
                      flex: 0,
                      child: Row(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          CatIcon(imagePath: (Cat2Ico(post.kategoria!.toString()))),
                          Checkbox(
                            value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                post.status = Bool2Int(value!);
                              });
                              saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!, index);
                              posts.sort(customCompare);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Note: As mentioned in another answer, in order for a widget to be displayed, it must be part of the widget tree. In this case, i wrapped the `GestureDetector` around the Container of the ListView item.

Hope it helps

Comment: OK... now code works much better - wrapping both FABs in a Column is good idea, however I cannot make them render on bottom of the screen. I tried Arrange or removing Column widget, but I got errors I could not solve (ie. compiler did not like 'if' statement after removing Column). Could you please advice how this can be done? Apparently  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat, does not work after adding Column widget because buttons are located on top center of screen.

Comment: OK... I have found it. I could use mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, in a Column...

Answer (score 2):

@Illusion is right: in order to display the button, it needs to be in the Widget tree.

Here's an example of a working Flutter app that shows the button on a long-press:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showButton = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          setState(() => showButton = true);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: showButton
          ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              label: const Text('Usuń'),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution in my code, but I am unable to make it working... I am doing something wrong for sure, but I do not see where it is... could you please take a look at update2 and advise... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I copied the example code from [`FloatingActionButton` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) and modified a bit to allow showing/hiding the FAB, this should give you some idea. The key points are to put `FloatingActionButton` in `Scaffold`'s `floatingActionButton` field and use some logic (I use basic `setState` here) to show/hide the FAB based on a `bool`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp());
}

class FloatingActionButtonExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const FloatingActionButtonExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FloatingActionButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<FloatingActionButtonExample> createState() =>
      _FloatingActionButtonExampleState();
}

class _FloatingActionButtonExampleState
    extends State<FloatingActionButtonExample> {
  // The FAB's foregroundColor, backgroundColor, and shape
  static const List<(Color?, Color? background, ShapeBorder?)> customizations =
      <(Color?, Color?, ShapeBorder?)>[
    (null, null, null),parameters.
    (null, Colors.green, null),
    (Colors.white, Colors.green, null),
    (Colors.white, Colors.green, CircleBorder()),
  ];
  int index = 0;
  bool showFab = false; // <-- to control FAB state shown/hidden

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FloatingActionButton Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // to change the state
                setState(() {
                  showFab = !showFab;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Press this to show/hide FAB'))),
      // use the FAB like this
      floatingActionButton: showFab
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  index = (index + 1) % customizations.length;
                });
              },
              foregroundColor: customizations[index].$1,
              backgroundColor: customizations[index].$2,
              shape: customizations[index].$3,
              child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```